# How to handle authentication to external registries using the Artifactory pull-through capacity

Tags: kubernetes, artifactory

I have a Kubernetes cluster, with Artifactory as my internal registry and proxy to pull images from external private registries. How do I authenticate to these external private registries when I want to pull an image from my Kubernetes cluster? Normally in Kubernetes, this is done by using image pull secrets, however, it is not clear if Artifactory is able to handle the secret to authenticate to the external regisitry. What alternatives do I have?

Comment: Configure artifactory to authenticate as it functions as the proxy

Comment: Ok, so you suggest doing it at the Artifactory level and you forget about the Kubernetes secrets. Did I understand correctly? It's a valid solution but could be cumbersome to maintain in the long run if there are a lot of registries. Thank you for your answer Ivonet.

Comment: If you can configure Artifactory through Secrets you should do so, but that is beside the point. You are using Artifactory as the application to handle the proxy calls to other repositories if you want to pull a third party image. Than that should also be the place where the auth is configured.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the comment by @Ivonet as the base - you configure the auth against the remote repository source in Artifactory itself. You can see the [docs here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Advanced+Settings#AdvancedSettings-RemoteCredentials).

Once Artifactory is setup, you set your `imagePullSecret` to auth against Artifactory itself. See some examples in [this knowledge-base article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-installing-and-managing-kubernetes-registries/)